# Wrong placement of elements on custom view created with xib

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib, nib

I'm writing my application in Swift 2.2, Xcode 7.3 (7D175) for iPhones from iOS 8.1 and above.

In my app I have two custom views, designed in xibs. The first view is `ContentView` and the second is `AudioView`. `ContentView` contains `AudioView's` instance as IBOutlet. In both of the xibs the constraints are set properly, there are IB warnings and when I resize the view in xib, it resizes perfectly corresponding to constraints. But, the problem is, when I add `AudioView` instance to `ContentView` instance, `AudioView's` subviews are misplaced, both in IB and in runtime.

Screenshot of AudioView:

[image: screenshot1]

Screenshot of ContentView:
[image: screenshot2]

As you can see, on first screenshot the elements are placed normally and, as I said before, on second they are misplaced. Here is the [link to my GitHub](https://github.com/vanelizarov/ContentView), I've uploaded the source code of this two classes and corresponding xibs to it. What should I do to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Try these links they contain your xibs i redid the constraints https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/546001/3652046/o5vEC4vpWrIdleA/AudioView.xib       https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/546001/3652046/VjTHqdNvNiaEutW/ContentView.xib

Comment: I've tried to use them, but expected the same result. Does it really work for you?